# Simplify the Search Code

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am developng an Application in vb.net and access as Backend

In the Search Form i have six controls - loanno,name,contact,sname,vno,vname. i want to search data in any given combined scenerios. My search query is given below

```
  If lno_txt.Text = "" And pname_txt.Text = "" And con_txt.Text = "" And sname_txt.Text = "" And vname_txt.Text = "" And vno_txt.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select any category")

    ElseIf lno_txt.Text <> "" And pname_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where lno like '%" + lno_txt.Text + "%' and pname like '%" + pname_txt.Text + "%'"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"

    ElseIf lno_txt.Text <> "" And con_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where lno like '%" + lno_txt.Text + "%' and (pc1 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%' or pc2 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%' or pc3 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%')"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"

    ElseIf lno_txt.Text <> "" And sname_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where lno like '%" + lno_txt.Text + "%' and (sname like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%' or sname2 like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%' or sname3 like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%')"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"

    ElseIf lno_txt.Text <> "" And vno_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where lno like '%" + lno_txt.Text + "%' and vno like '%" + vno_txt.Text + "%'"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"

    ElseIf lno_txt.Text <> "" And vname_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where lno like '%" + lno_txt.Text + "%' and vname-yr like '%" + vname_txt.Text + "%'"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"

    ElseIf sname_txt.Text <> "" And con_txt.Text <> "" Then
        Dim sql As String = "select * from party where (sname like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%' or sname2 like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%' or sname3 like '%" + sname_txt.Text + "%') and (pc1 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%' or pc2 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%' or pc3 like '%" + con_txt.Text + "%') "
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "aa")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "aa"
```

Can anyone please Simplify the above Search coding

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique query with all the filters and ask for the condition or if the parameter is null.

ej.

```
select * from mytable where (filter1 = @param or @param is null)
and (filter2 = @param2 or @param2 is null)
and (filter3 = @param3 or @param3 is null)
```

Also, beware of using parameters instead of concatenating strings, your code is asking for an sql injection. Also, specify fields explicitly, avoid using *

Comment: Can u explain in detail plz Ji